# How to add new Org to existing hyperledger channel?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I want to add new org to existing channel using configtxlator tool.
I could convert the config proto file to JSON using configtxlator tool but where to add new Org details in JSON config file and also i can see below key value pairs in JSON config of existing orgs.

```
"value": {
            "config": {                                                                 
                 "admins": ["LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBDRVJUSUZJQ0FURS0tL...."],
```

In case of adding new org details is the above key `admins` is base64 encoded?

Answer (score 0):

I believe all of the certificates are actually hex-encoded strings.
You might also want to have a look at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DKuGU5CYV_E (this video was recently published and details adding an org to a channel)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the organization in the channel config to `channel_group.groups.Application.groups.<ORG_NAME>`.

Here you can find example code: https://github.com/sandp125/FabricNodeAPI_V1/blob/master/app/channel-config.js#L59-L70

Afterwards you have to calculate the proto diff to send it as a channel update. More info: http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release/configtx.html#configuration-updates